# Split String into two and know its elements

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift4

I have a string that has a url and some text ! The text can be before the url or after the url. So how can I split the string in two and know which one is Text and which one is URL.

For example String 1 = " This is stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask" (text is before the url)

String 2 = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask This is stack overflow" (text is after the url)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsdatadetector

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution.

func getAttributedText(_ text1:String,text2:String) -> NSAttributedString {

let attributedString1 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"(text1)\n", attributes: nil)

let attributedString2 = NSMutableAttributedString(string:"(text2)\n", attributes:nil)

attributedString1.append(attributedString2)

return attributedString1
}

let originalString = "https://medium.com/@felicity.johnson.mail/how-to-split-a-string-swift-3-0-e9b757445064 checking new post"

```
                do {
                    let types: NSTextCheckingResult.CheckingType = .link
                    let detector = try? NSDataDetector(types: types.rawValue)
                    let matches = detector?.matches(in: originalString, options: .reportCompletion, range: NSMakeRange(0, originalString.count))
                    var link:String!
                    if (matches != nil){
                        for match in matches! {
                            link = (match.url?.absoluteString)!

                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    let mutableAttributedString = NSMutableAttributedString(string: originalString, attributes: nil)


                    let attributedText = getAttributedText("DOJ watchdog finds no bias in launch of Trump-Russia probe, but uncovers ‘significant’ FBI errors", text2:"The Justice Department’s inspector general, in a long-awaited review concerning the origins of the Russia investigation \n")

                    let userContent : String = ""

           // Get range of text to replace
                    if let range = mutableAttributedString.string.range(of: link){
                        let nsRange = NSRange(range, in: mutableAttributedString.string)

      // Replace content in range with the new content
                        mutableAttributedString.replaceCharacters(in: nsRange, with: userContent)
                    }
          let userTypedContent = mutableAttributedString.string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    let urlContent = attributedText.string.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespaces)
                    UIlablel.text = urlContent + userTypedContent }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
let str = "This is stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
let array = str.components(separatedBy: " ")
let result = array.first { $0.contains("http") }
```

Answer (score 0):

If the sentence have space between text and **url** you can get the url following way.  :

```
let string = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet"
let stringArray = string.componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet(NSCharacterSet.whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet())

print(stringArray.last)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this (but handle white spaces and Optionals):

```
let sentence =  "This is stack overflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask and may be some more text."

let words = sentence.components(separatedBy: " ")

if let url = words.first(where: { $0.contains("http") }) {

    let splits = sentence.components(separatedBy: url)
    let prefix = splits.first
    let suffix = splits.last

    print(prefix)   // "This is stack overflow "
    print(url)      // "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask"
    print(suffix)   // " and may be some more text."
}
```